# Hive logfile setting

Tags: hive, log4j, log4j2

I'm using Hive3.1.2 on win10, when I use hive in the command window, I only want to see the log output of warn level and above, but I don't know how to set the log4j2.properties file.The following is the log settings:
[part of the log code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVXJy.png)

I have tried typing "set hive.root.logger=warn;" in the console, but it has no effect (there is no such attribute). I also changed the level from info to warn in log4j.properties file, after restarting hive, it still does not work. If you know how to set up log4j2 file, or use an older log4j file, please tell me how to do it.